# counting a certain amount of items in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find a way to count the number of store that may have a certain item on hand (sku). I keep getting 0 as my output however I know that is not true since this item was just released to certain stores. I have tried without the DISTINCT keyword as well and it still does not work. 
The table w_store has the sku and store location and table alc_loc has the amount given to that store and the sku as well.

```
select distinct count(*) as total_stores
from(
select distinct a.store
from w_store a
join alc_loc b
on
b.item = a.sku 
where a.sku = 1001
and b.cal_qty = b.all_qty
group by a.store, a.sku
having (a.sku) = 1
)a;
```

My desired output would just be a column that just has the total number of stores. I just don't really know what to do to pull the data I need. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: These kind of questions will be more clear if there is sample data and expected result present..

Comment: What do you mean "due to sales and seeing them there personally"? You surely can't rely on viewing the product in a store to determine if it will be in the database. Having worked a number of positions from store manager, to database dev, your product count and actual count on hand are two (sometimes very) different things. Aside from that, `having (a.sku) = 1` doesn't seem right. Try `having count(*) >= 1` instead. Edit: Joining on the qty fields also seems to be a terrible approach. What does your table structure look like?

Comment: I tried using having count(*) >= 1 and it brought back "ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
01476. 00000 -  "divisor is equal to zero" "

Comment: Can you also clarify what kind of sample data you need? I would be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you are trying to write:

```
select count(*) as total_stores
from (select s.store
      from w_store s join
           alc_loc l
           on l.item = s.sku and l.cal_qty = s.all_qty
      where s.sku = 1001
      group by s.store
      having count(*) = 1
     ) sl;
```

Notes:

- I don't see what the quantity has to do.  I suspect that is causing the query not to have any matches.  Perhaps you want `<=` instead.
- Note the use of meaningful table aliases (instead of `a` and `b`).
- `select distinct count(*)` doesn't make sense.

The query you really want may look more like this:

```
select count(distinct s.store) as total_stores
from w_store s join
     alc_loc l
     on l.item = s.sku
where s.sku = 1001 and l.cal_qty > 0;
```